# Secure way to login and logout in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

in my website i use session variable to maintain the "email" field value from log in form , 
for logging out i redirect the user to another page and put the session variable to null.
my question is: is it secure to implement the log in and log-out process in this way? and what is the best way to do that in the following program

```
public partial class Staff : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string value = Session["email"].ToString();                
            Classes.AddAddress addcuid = new Classes.AddAddress(value);             
            staffNamelbl.Text = addcuid.addStaffName().ToString();                               
    }
}
```

}

```
public partial class Logout : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Session["email"] = null;
        Response.Write("you logged out from system!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its pretty secure the way you have it. While logging out use
`Session.Abandon()`
and then redirect the user to your home page `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")`.

For logging in store the email after matching the password `Session("user") = email` and check if the session is active every time you access a restricted part of your application using

```
if (Session.Item("user") == null) {
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
else 
\\grant access
```

If you are accessing a database to match user credentials make sure you either use prepared statements or parametric sql queries.

Answer (score 2):

For the Secure way of logging in and out in ASP.NET and MVC apps is to use the built in Microsoft Web Security class and methods.
Here is info about the WebSecurity class(es):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: WebForms is supported too! I'd advise to look into it for the most secure method(s) :) It grants and revokes tokens, allows you to use external authentication providers, Windows Authentication, LDAP, forms based authentication. I'd highly suggest you to utilize it!